# How to Create CRUD operations with Admin Grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, crud

How to create the CRUD operations with Admin Grid in Magento 2?

I want to :

1. First of create frontend input form.
2. frontend input form data get in admin grid.
3. In admin grid Create delete options.
4. In admin Grid Create edit (UPDATE) options.

How to achieve this. Please give the best way and the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Create the CRUD operations with Admin Grid in Magento 2***

**Step-1 :** Choose your Module Name like VendoreName and ModuleName

**Step-2 :** Create a folder like this /app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName

**Step-3 :** First create registration.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName

**Step-4 :** Create module.xml at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc

**Step-5 :** Choose admin route name and  create in routes.xml at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml

**Step-6 :** Create on table structure add into InstallSchema.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Setup

**Step-7 :** Create Model files for access your table for DML operation.

**Step-8 :** Choose admin Conroller name(Index) and create folder like this app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Index

**Step-9 :** Create your admin Action file for create admin pages At app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Index  for show
grid and manupulate data in admingrid.(Index.php,Add.php,Delete.php,Edit.php,MassDelete.php,MassStatus.php,Save.php)

**Step-10**: But right now our module is not show. Now Create one menu and add this menu into magento menu list. craete menu.xml at
app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml (Menu action must assige
carefull like AdminRouteName/AdminControllerName/AtcionFileName)

**Step-11**: Now we have to create layout at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout (file name must
be like this adminroutname_admincontollername_actionfilename.xml  all
latters are small case and same as you define in file.)

**Step-12**: You can create grid using Block and Ui-component follow this [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

**Step-13**: Now admin part is over So create frontend route name routes.xml at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend

**Step-14**: Create Frontend Contoller Name Folder like (Index)  like app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Index

**Step-15**: create action in it as you required. (Index.php,Add.php,Delete.php,Edit.php,MassDelete.php,MassStatus.php,Save.php)

**Step-16**: create layout for it. layout name must be like this frontendroutename_frontendcontrollername_frontendactionfilename.xml

**Step-17**: in layout file you call Block and phtml files for show content. [click here for more](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html)

**Step-18**: Now your module is ready to use

> **Please check this all files are created and running well** [click here to show](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFMtTOkwbaPKbIdAZ_DDZKJkZHvpIoPW/view)

***Note: you can also use some step before and after as you comfort. but some step are required like route create, layout create etc***

***I Hope This Helps You***

Comment: Thanks but i want to without module creator. And you explains step create. You only share me steps. Thanks

Comment: Yes without any module creator

Comment: Thank you . your module All steps is best and i  make  +1 upvote but your provided module doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, i have find Your module is working perfect. My magento 2 problem.Thanks @Msquare.

Comment: and other Please one request check this link and provide debug step . https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/317559/85907