# Create New Module get 404 error(How to debug code)

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, controllers

**`Hello,`**

I have create new custom module and run frontend  get 404 Page error.

**How to debug module what problem in code ?**

Please Help me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: First thing which comes to my mind for 404 is routes check the routes for the module.

Comment: routes.xml file is well

Comment: share your routes.xml code along with your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Check This Steps***

**Step-1 :** First you need to check your module is enable or not.

**Step-2 :** You need to check are you working on right magento url or not.

**Step-3 :** Check your Route name in routes.xml app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\etc\frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="yourroutename" id="yourroutename">
            <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step-4 :** In above File  must be there

**Step-5 :** Then create contoller (Index) app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index

**Step-6 :** Add Action file like this (Index.php) at app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index (Class Name and File Name must be same)

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Step-7 :** Create layout for it in app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout

**Step-8 :** Layout File name must be like this **FrontendRouteName_FrontendControllerName_ActionFileName.xml**

**Step-9 :** Add Blank Page layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">

    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Step-10 : Must be Run Magento Upgrade command before check in fronend.

Note: You can check and Compare your code with above code.

***I Hope This helps You***

Comment: i have already solve issues.but i think your code is right so +1 upvote. thanks.@Msquare