# How debug a Magento module issue started from frontend

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento 2.3.3 installed with some modules. There is one module that has been uninstalled before still display on frontend. It looks to me either the module could not be uninstalled completely or I made mistake on identifying the module.

Is there an approach I could trace which part / module contributing a button ( I want to remove ) from the frontend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Commerce Bug](https://store.pulsestorm.net/l/commerce-bug-three) for debugging Magento 2.

Comment: But Its paid. Can you suggest any other.

Comment: instead of the tool, is there documentation that could guide a method/skill for debug this? there are many tools definitely but skills are still required. could you give a pointer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This paid tool really is the difference between fighting Magento and working with Magento. Myself and coworkers have been looking for a viable FOSS alternative for quite some time. It might comfort you that [you're probably already familiar with](https://alanstorm.com/) the guy who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will explain how to uninstall a module.

Steps to uninstall a composer installed module

```
php bin/magento module:disable Namespace_ModuleName
php bin/magento module:uninstall Namespace_ModuleName
composer remove namespace/module-name
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Steps to uninstall a manually added module in **`app/code`**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Namespace_ModuleName
remove directory from app/code manually
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After you follow the above steps, you need to check if the module is disabled or not.

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

[Create New Module get 404 error(How to debug code)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317559/create-new-module-get-404-errorhow-to-debug-code)

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: thank you. but i have done these steps many times. my issue as said is not how to uninstall the module, it is i even unable to find out which module is the culprit.