# Admin Grid wont show and getting "Request validation failed for action" error in debug

Tags: magento2.3, admin, grid, menu, di

I was trying to create an admin grid in the adminhtml trying to learn how they function and work and I ran into an issue following this guide: [Mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html#step-4-create-controller). I've been trying to debug where the issue is and, to the best of my knowledge I found that the issue lies somewhere in the core files of my module which are:

1. di.xml
2. layout files (or their name)
3. menu.xml
4. routes.xml

And here is my code, I am sharing mine because, of course, I made adjustments to the naming of the fields and the database fields.

> Request/Price/Controller/Adminhtml/Blog/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Request\Price\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

public function __construct(
    Context     $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Posts')));

    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

> Request/Price/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Request_Price::menu"
         title="Request Price" module="Request_Price"
         sortOrder="10"
         resource="Magento_Customer::customer"/>

    <add id="Request_Price::menu_item"
         title="Price Requests" module="Request_Price"
         sortOrder="10" parent="Request_Price::menu"
         action="request_price/create/index"
         resource="Request_Price::menu_item"/>
</menu>
```

> Request/Price/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="request_price" frontName="request_price">
            <module name="Request_Price"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Request/Price/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="request_price_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">
                  Request\Price\Model\ResourceModel\Price\Grid\Collection
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Request\Price\Model\ResourceModel\Price\Grid\Collection"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">request_price</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Request\Price\Model\ResourceModel\Price</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> Request/Price/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Request\Price\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Zend_Db_Exception;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * @throws Zend_Db_Exception
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('request_price')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('request_price')
            )
                ->addColumn(
                    'request_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                    ],
                    'Request'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'username',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'username'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'email',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Email '
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'message_area',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    500,
                    ['nullable' => true],
                    'Message'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'Name',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Name'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                    'Created At'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'status'
                )
                ->setComment('Request Table');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

            $installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
                $installer->getTable('request_price'),
                $setup->getIdxName(
                    $installer->getTable('request_price'),
                    ['username', 'email', 'message_area', 'Name'],
                    AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                ),
                ['username', 'email', 'message_area', 'Name'],
                AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error every time I try to access my menu item in my *debug.log*

> [2021-10-10 12:20:48] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at D:\Work\mag6\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Request\BackendValidator.php:176)"} []

This is my file system, just in case I got the name of something wrong

[image: File System]

And, this is what I see when I open the new grid

[image: Grid]

I Would appreciate your help, fellow Magento developers. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1: I found what was the issue, I named the layout file was named incorrectly so when I changed its name from request_price_post_index to request_price_blog_index the layout worked but unfortunately I get this new error when I open the new grid**

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML
> in file
> "D:/Work/mag6/app/code/Request/Price/view/adminhtml/ui_component/request_price_listing.xml"
> is invalid: Element 'argument': This element is not expected. Line: 39
>
> Verify the XML and try again.
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML
> in file
> "D:/Work/mag6/app/code/Request/Price/view/adminhtml/ui_component/request_price_listing.xml"
> is invalid: Element 'argument': This element is not expected. Line: 39

and the code for the ui_component is as follows:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="request_price/post/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Post</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete
                                selected items?
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </listingToolbar>

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">
                request_price_listing.request_price_listing_data_source
            </item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">
                request_price_listing.request_price_listing_data_source
            </item>
        </item>

        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">requestcoloumn</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="request_price_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">
                Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
            </argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">request_price_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <columns name="requestcoloumn">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!--        <column name="product_name">-->
        <!--            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
        <!--                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
        <!--                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
        <!--                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>-->
        <!--                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
        <!--                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Name</item>-->
        <!--                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">12</item>-->
        <!--                </item>-->
        <!--            </argument>-->
        <!--        </column>-->


        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317429/82670

Comment: @Msquare you can see that i pretty much have most of what is listed in that question, save for the Admin actions but even without them the panel SHOULD appear even if its actions do not function. So, if I can fix that first, then ill add more files into the mix to avoid "Integration Hell".

Answer (score 0):

Edit your di.xml

Replace

`Request\Price\Model\ResourceModel\Price\Collection`

with

`Request\Price\Model\ResourceModel\Price\Grid\Collection`

into two places

For more details:[Sample grid](https://github.com/AshokMarthineni/Admin-Grid-Sample-Module--Magento)

Comment: That didnt work, unfortunately. i will update my question with the screenshots of the new Di.xml and what I see when I open the grid